# Vue: How to communicate with a particular child component from parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to pass data sent by the server to a designated child component. This is how I have added the components to the parent component:

```
<my-order v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id" :generalData="order"></my-order>
```

Though a component can be identified by the `key`, I do not understand how can I reach a particular element (say, I want to change the content in a `<span>` of a particular `my-order` identified by `key`) and change its content.

```
Orders
    Order [key=1]
    Order [key=2]
    Order [key=3]
```

Let's say `Order [key=2]` has been updated in the backend and I want to reflect that change in the client. So I want to update this particular `Order [key=2]` in the client.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. What are you trying to do? Can you give us an example (with minimal code, preferably)?

Comment: :) I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need put the dynamic data inside `orders`.

Ex:

Server API return this `orders` json:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 100,
    "some_data": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 50,
    "some_data": "Anything you can think"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": 75,
    "some_data": null
  }
]
```

in your component you just use the data:

```js
<my-order v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id" :generalData="order">
    //Inside the component

    <span v-if="generalData.some_data !== null">{{generalData.some_data}}</span>

    //End Inside Component
</my-order>
```

this way, each `order` will get your unique data, or span will not render if `some_data` is `null`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Vue and learning... Will try as you mentioned above.

Comment: What happens if the data is received after the components are created. As I described in my use case above. Already components have been created and I just want to sync them with the server.

Comment: The Vue will renderize the new data, if orders had 6 order, and now has 10, the Vue will update the DOM with the updated data.